# Mixture model on binary + continuous data

Tags: clustering, finite-mixture-model, latent-class, mixed-type-data

If I have a dataset of continuous variables (that I can assume are normally distributed), I can identify subgroups using a Gaussian mixture model and implement.
Likewise if I have binary data I can model it as a mixture of Bernoulli.

I can implement either of these models using likelihood EM approach, or MCMC (typically Gibbs) sampling.

However, if my dataset comprises both continuous and binary data, can a mixture model be defined? If so, how?

Comment: Yes, it can. I shall expand into an answer later. However, why would you not be able to define a mixture model? Consider the likelihood function for one person in either type of model: it's the product of all the probabilities that their indicators were equal to whatever was observed. Why can't this adapt to mixed types of indicators? Also see this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/339936/mixing-variable-types-in-latent-class-profile-analysis

Comment: I hadn't seen it done before or implemented in any general probabilistic programming frameworks. Do you know if any existing software can infer such models or do custom Gibbs samplers need to be written?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Bayesian implementations. I have fit a model in Stata with mixed types of indicators. I am almost sure that MPlus can do this also. I believe that the R package `flexmix` does; its function `FLXMVcombi` says that "This model driver can be used to cluster mixed-mode binary and Gaussian data. It checks which columns of a matrix contain only zero and ones, and does the same as `FLXMCmvbinary` for them. For the remaining columns of the data matrix independent Gaussian distributions are used ..."

Comment: Ah great, I didn't realise it was quite as straight forward as simply incorporating the different data type into the likelihood product. I'll check out that `flexmix` implementation, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simply combine the two components of you make a simple independence assumption.

Then P(continuous, binary) = P(continuous) P(binary) and you already have the solution of the right hand side.

For binary variables I don't think you *want* to use a dependent model here, but it is equally easy to do for at least one or two variables.