# Mixture Model: Data Consist of Continuous and Binary Features

Tags: clustering, binary-data, continuous-data, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I have a features like below

| id | x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 | x5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 0.4 | 1.4 | 5.6 | 1 | 0 |
| id2 | -0.01 | 0.5 | -3.4 | 0 | 1 |

where x1, x2, x3 are continuous features and x4 and x5 are binary. The goal is to find $k$ clusters using Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM). However, given there are binary features (i.e., x4, x5) along with continuous ones, I'm not certain whether GMM is appropriate. Any guidance to modeling and / or pointers to published papers would be appreciated.

Note I did look at [Mixture model on binary + continuous data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/425671/257814), but I'm looking for concrete / research papers.